# Merging two SELECTs into one from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I tried the UNION but it doesn't work it says #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY.

```
SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber1
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo
WHERE friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1
ORDER BY members.Name

UNION

SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber2
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
WHERE friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1
ORDER BY members.Name
```

Both of the queries work great on their own but I am trying to have them in one query because I want to "for each" on the result set in JSTL after that. I also tried creating an alias for friends.MemberNumber1 and friends.MemberNumber2 but it didn't change anything. Maybe there is also a simpler query I'm just not seeing. Or do I absolutely need to make two queries?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need just one order by at the end? or use parenthasis

Comment: Wow thanks for that, I tried with parentheses, with 1 order by, but not the two at the same time... it works now! Thanks.(I feel dumb)

Comment: WARNING it doesn't work if I don't alias the friends.MemberNumber1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a derived table, then order by.
The column names have to match up.
I know this answer is close to Barmar's, but the aliasName for the second column is important.
You can also look up the difference between UNION and UNION ALL, I use the latter typically.

```
SELECT Name , MemberNumber
FROM (
    SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber1 as MemberNumber
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo
    WHERE friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber2 as MemberNumber
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
    WHERE friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1) AS derived1
ORDER BY derived1.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `UNION` into a subquery, then order the entire thing.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber1
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo
    WHERE friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1

    UNION

    SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber2
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
    WHERE friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1) AS u
ORDER BY u.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT members.Name,     friends.MemberNumber1
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON         friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo
WHERE friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1)

UNION

(SELECT members.Name,     friends.MemberNumber2
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
WHERE friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1)
ORDER BY members.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

it also satisfy your query logic?

```
SELECT members.Name, friends.MemberNumber1
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo 
WHERE friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1 OR friends.[primarykey] IN (

SELECT friend.[primarykey]
FROM friends
INNER JOIN members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
WHERE friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
            *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
            Name = members.Name,
            MemberNumber = friends.MemberNumber1
    FROM    
            friends
    INNER JOIN 
            members 
            ON friends.MemberNumber1= members.MemNo
    WHERE 
            friends.MemberNumber2 LIKE 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            Name = members.Name, 
            MemberNumber = friends.MemberNumber2
    FROM 
            friends
    INNER JOIN 
            members ON friends.MemberNumber2= members.MemNo
    WHERE 
            friends.MemberNumber1 LIKE 1

) Unioned
ORDER BY 
            Unioned.Name
```

If `UNION ALL` gives issues, try `UNION`